# Capture JavaScript events in C or C++ Windows Application

Tags: javascript, c++, c

I'm currently using IWebBrowser2 C++ which I've managed to call JavaScript functions from the native client side.

Which I use the following to do:

```
void CallWebPage::OnDocumentComplete(LPCTSTR strURL,LPDISPATCH pDisp)
{
    m_bDocumentComplete = true;
    m_webPage.SetDocument(pDisp);
    UpdateAllViews(NULL,HINT_ON_DOCUMENT_COMPLETE);

    // Call FunctionTest function on JavaScript side
    m_webPage.CallJavaScriptFunction("FunctionTest");
}
```

However I'm looking for a way of picking up JavaScript events inside my application.

for example:

If I was to type inside a input field on the JavaScript side, I would be able to pick that up inside my windows application and print out what was typed inside that input field.

So I would like some guidence on how I would go about doing this and to know if it's possible to do this?

**If there is a way of doing it in C or C++ then that would be great.**

Comment: There is no language C/C++. This is not C, so do not add C tag!

Comment: @Olaf Sorry I didn't make it clear enough the C/C++ was to say either C or C++. I added the C tag because I don't mind if anyone could give an answer in C